# Sorting a query based on a category preference using LINQ/Lambda in asp MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

The scenario is:

I have a list of products and can be grouped into categories. Here is the the **product model**:

```
public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is the **category model**:

```
public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Dummy data:

*categories:
A
B
C
D*

What I want:

I want to list **all products**, but the products which belong to the **C category** is listed on the top of the list, then the rest is as it is on the bottom of the list.

What would be the linq statement for this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally do it like this...

```
var preferredCategory = "CategoryC";
var result = Products.OrderBy(x => x.Category.Name == preferredCategory ? 0 : 1).
                      ThenBy(x => <Your previous ordering>);
```

Comment: OP asked for linq, not lambda.

Comment: @DavidG: This a LINQ expression using lambda expressions, what's the problem?

Comment: Well I guess you can argue that, but one would assume OP is asking for pure Linq.

Comment: It is okay with this one. In fact I was hoping this lambda expression. Sorry if I confused you guys with the tittle. Thanks to all of you guys

Comment: There is nothing less "pure LINQ" about this answer. It uses the expression syntax which has lambda expression whereas yours uses the query syntax. Considering one of them "less LINQ" than the other is like saying a Ferrari is more of a car than a Lamborghini.

Comment: @DavidG That **is** LINQ. Query syntax and method syntax are semantically identical. In fact, [query syntax is actually translated into method syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) behind the scenes before it can be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to do this would be to use `OrderBy` with arbitrary value.

```
var products = Enumerable.Empty<Product>();

var sorted1 = products.OrderByDescending(p => p.Category.Name == "C");
var sorted2 = from p in products
              orderby p.Category.Name == "C" descending
              select p;
```

Comment: Possibly because the OP asked for Linq?

Comment: Sorry if for the title, actually I was hoping either linq or lambda. I edited it though, thanks for all of you guys.